# JSF 2.2 ajax no refresh multipart/form-data

Tags: ajax, jsf, refresh, multipartform-data

I have a problem and i simplfied the code to show you.

```
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h:panelGroup id="images">
            <h:inputText id="auctionImage" value="#{testBean.nowy}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Add">
                <f:ajax execute="auctionImage" render="images"/>
            </h:commandButton>


                <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.elements}" var="oneImage">
                    <h:outputText value="#{oneImage.title}" />
                </ui:repeat>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:form>
```

This is my main Bean

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class TestBean {
    private List<Element> elements;
private String nowy;

    public String getNowy() {
        return nowy;
    }

    public void setNowy(String nowy) {
        Element el = new Element();
        el.setTitle(nowy);
        if(elements==null) elements = new ArrayList<>();
        elements.add(el);
        this.nowy = nowy;
    }
    public List<Element> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setElements(List<Element> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

}
```

This is the element class

```
@ManagedBean
public class Element {
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

I want to populate the list everytime I click Add button and print it using ajax. The list is populated but ajax refresh the panelGroup only for the first time. To make it work again I have to refresh website. What i do wrong?

Comment: The code doesn't match the question title/text. I'm not seeing a `<h:inputFile>` anywhere.

Comment: right, it was there but i simplified code to show the essence of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i was managed to resolve the issue. Well, to be honest it wasn't me but jsf programmers. I found out that it happens when you use

```
 <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

with ajax. This is the bug and it has been repaired some time ago. You just have to update your jsf version.
http://javaserverfaces.java.net/ - i got 2.2.3 version which is the newest for now.

After restarting glassfish and redeploying application everything works just fine.